# Как можно сделать выборку товаров и прочего вверху поля написания сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram

Видел в одном из телеграм ботов, выборку блюд вверху поля для написания сообщения, скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на inline кнопку в поле для написания текста подставляются данные, после можно нажать на какое-либо блюдо и получить о нем информацию, как можно сделать такой же выпадающий список благодаря aiogram и возможно ли это вообще сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было по гуглить чуть больше. Это называется инлайн режим. Вот держи:
https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/inline_mode/